# Manipulação Diretórios java/python/c

Tags: java, python, c, arquivo

Tenho um diretório A, e esse diretório A possui vários subdiretórios, e em cada subdiretório, possui quantidade variadas de arquivos. Eu gostaria de colocar os arquivos todos em um diretório na ordem em que eles estão nos subdiretórios, alguma ideia de como posso fazer isso em java, python ou c ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hummm esse tipo de pergunta no stackoverflow.com seria denunciada, ja que não é uma duvida sobre um erro ou algo do tipo, você esta simplesmente pedindo para que alguem resolva um problema para você. Entretanto como dito [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1/aqui-no-o-stackoverflow-com?cb=1), este site não é o stackoverflow.com. Então fiz um script python para te ajudar ja que eu estava sem sono mesmo.

crie o arquivo copia.py com o codigo à seguir:

```
import os
import sys

origem = sys.argv[1]
destino = sys.argv[2]

if not os.path.exists(destino):
    os.makedirs(destino)

for raiz, subDiretorios, arquivos in os.walk(origem):
    for arquivo in arquivos:
        arqCaminho = os.path.join(raiz, arquivo)
        novoArqNome = "%s/%s" % (destino, arqCaminho.replace('/', '_'))
        os.rename(arqCaminho, novoArqNome)
```

criei a seguinte estrutura para testar na pasta dirA:

```
$ tree dirA/
dirA/
├── arq1.foo
├── subDir1
│   ├── arq1.foo
│   ├── arq2.foo
│   ├── arq3.foo
│   ├── arq4.foo
│   └── subSubDir1
│       ├── arq1.foo
│       └── arq2.foo
├── subDir2
│   └── arq1.foo
└── subDir3
    ├── arq1.foo
    ├── arq2.foo
    └── arq3.foo
```

você executa o script da seguinte forma:

```
$python copia.py dirA/ destino
```

e você tera o seguinte resultado:

```
$ tree destino/
destino/
├── dirA_arq1.foo
├── dirA_subDir1_arq1.foo
├── dirA_subDir1_arq2.foo
├── dirA_subDir1_arq3.foo
├── dirA_subDir1_arq4.foo
├── dirA_subDir1_subSubDir1_arq1.foo
├── dirA_subDir1_subSubDir1_arq2.foo
├── dirA_subDir2_arq1.foo
├── dirA_subDir3_arq1.foo
├── dirA_subDir3_arq2.foo
└── dirA_subDir3_arq3.foo
```

note que renomeei o arquivo com o caminho+nome do arquivo e substitui as `/` por `_` para que você possa manter os arquivos na ordem por nome como se estivessem na pasta. note como nos comandos `tree` os arquivos mantem a mesma ordem apesar de ja nao estarem hierarquizados por pastas.

Answer (score 1):

Para que tudo isso se o  shutil resolve seu problema

```
import shutil
shutil.copytree(diretorioA, diretorioB, symlinks=False, ignore=None)
```

faz cópia exata e recursiva de um diretório. Já testei isso no windows e linux e não tem nenhum problema.